# Fancy Button with animation

Tags: android, animation

I want to create a 2-state-switch button (on/off) like in doubletwist alarm clock

-> http://www.design-by-izo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Screenshot_2012-03-30-20-11-30.png

When pressing the button it switches its caption with a fancy slide-in effect.
I already know about android animations, but anyhow I dont get this work within a single view.

EDIT: is there any way to do this, prior to ICS? (without taking ICS' code...)

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for an [android switch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) - It's already been done for you.  You just need to supply your own custom images for the switch's style

Comment: @ThomasK well the app you showed was ICS :) but before ICS it was the ToggleButton:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html   You might consider looking into the ICS source for how they did the switch and implement it yourself

Answer (score 0):

There is no slide effect on Android like on iPhone. However doing a two-state btn is easy. Just create an xml file like this and put the drawables in the folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/my_btn_pressed_bkgnd" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/my_btn_disabled_bkgnd" android:state_enabled="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/my_btn_unpressed_bkgnd" android:state_enabled="true"/>
```